# Cannot use xgreek in XeLatex with Fedora

Tags: xetex, hyphenation, greek

I am trying to enable greek hyphenation in a XeLatex document. But when I do I get:

```
|Package `xgreek' version 2.4 by Apostolos Syropoulos
|! Undefined control sequence.
|\ds@monogreek ->\language \l@monogreek
l.445 \ExecuteOptions{monogreek}
?
|! Emergency stop.
|\ds@monogreek ->\language \l@monogreek
|l.445 \ExecuteOptions{monogreek}
```

Here is a snippet to reproduce it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

For what is worth I'm using Fedora and my XeTex version is 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013). If I recall correctly I didn't have issues with other Linux distributions, so this may be a distribution-specific issue ?

Comment: You probably didn't install the specific package for Greek language support with `yum`.

Comment: I can already write in greek; it's just that greek words don't hyphenate for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

The code-snippet is empty. Package 'xgreek' is not necessary to write greek (polytonic or
monotonic). Working with Xe(La)Tex the following MWE perhaps will help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Minion Pro} %% Select your favourite font
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}

This is english.

Γιατί δεν λειτοργεί;
\end{document}
```

Comment: This fails as in my original post, i.e. ! Undefined control sequence. \ds@monogreek ->\language \l@monogreek etc.

Comment: @ruediger: in your example you use both `xgreek` and `polyglossia`, which have the same purpose (in this case), to handle mixed greek and english documents. I cannot see the reason for using them at the same time. Of course `polyglossia` is much more general, and the only way to go if you have more languages; however, I have found that `xgreek` works better in some cases, `polyglossia` does seem to have bugs.